# error in running a for loop for a big dataset in R

Tags: r

i have a dataset that has the daily returns of 900 companies. I want to calculate Ri x Rj for the companies for each date, where Ri and Rj are the returns for the ith and jth company respectively.

My data set looks like this:

```
Company Code         Date           r
ABB.NS             2008-08-01       0.98
ABB.NS             2008-08-02       0.96
.
.
ABAN               2008-08-01       0.92
ABAN               2008-08-02       0.87
```

I created a function multiplier for the same. It works fine for a small sample. However, my dataset is huge and will output around 8,00,000 values of RiRj.So, i included a check statement (print(length(z)) to monitor the progress of the loop. Now the function below, when used on the entire data goes into some kind of a repetitive loop. I think it may be because of the print statement (8,00,000 entries dont get printed at a time maybe?). But on removing the print statement, it returns only the check statement  ie print(length(z)) and not RiRj. is there a way around this somehow?

```
multiplier <- function(x)
{  
  z <- vector()
  for(i in 1:(length(x)))
  { 
    k <- length(x)*(i-1)
    for(j in 1:length(x))
    {
      z[k+j] <- x[i]*x[j]

      if((k+j)%%1000 == 0)
      {
            print(length(z))
      }
    } 
  }
print(z)
}

Ri.Rj <- aggregate(Companies$r, list(Companies$Date), FUN=multiplier)
Ri.Rj <- setDT(Ri.Rj)[, list(x = unlist(x)), by = Group.1]
colnames(Ri.Rj) <- c('Date', 'RiRj')
```

Comment: Use `combn` instead of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Companies)
setkey(DT, Date)
DT[,list(RiRj=Reduce(`*`,CJ(r,r))), by=Date]
#         Date   RiRj
#1: 2008-08-01 0.8464
#2: 2008-08-01 0.9016
#3: 2008-08-01 0.9016
#4: 2008-08-01 0.9604
#5: 2008-08-02 0.7569
#6: 2008-08-02 0.8352
#7: 2008-08-02 0.8352
#8: 2008-08-02 0.9216
```

Or

```
DT[, CJ(r,r), by=Date][, RiRj:=V1*V2][,c(1,4), with=FALSE]
```

Based on your code:

```
 aggregate(Companies$r, list(Companies$Date), FUN=multiplier)
 #     Group.1    x.1    x.2    x.3    x.4
 #1 2008-08-01 0.9604 0.9016 0.9016 0.8464
 #2 2008-08-02 0.9216 0.8352 0.8352 0.7569
```

#### data

```
Companies <- structure(list(Company.Code = c("ABB.NS", "ABB.NS", "ABAN", "ABAN"
), Date = structure(c(14092, 14093, 14092, 14093), class = "Date"), 
r = c(0.98, 0.96, 0.92, 0.87)), .Names = c("Company.Code", 
"Date", "r"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```